# Abrir página numa determinada secção

Tags: jquery, html

Eu gostaria que ao clicar em um link (ex: carros esportivos) a nova página, assim que carregada, executasse uma animação até a localização do "tópico" carros esportivos.

Segue o meu projeto:

http://andrellfreire.esy.es/Treinamentos.html

Na parte de cursos tem a opção dsg 7 e ao clicar nela a página de detalhes > http://andrellfreire.esy.es/Treinamentoslista.html é carregada, no entanto eu queria que ela desliza-se até a parte do dsg 7 (ou que já fosse carregada nela o que seria melhor). O mesmo iria acontecer nas outras opções.

Agradeço desde já pela ajuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*...ou que já fosse carregada nela o que seria melhor...*". Para isso não precisa de usar jQuery, visto que o browser (navegador) faz isso por nós, truque é inserir o `id` da secção da página onde quer ir parar também no URL. Veja se é isto que pretende:

http://andrellfreire.esy.es/Treinamentos.html#cursos
http://andrellfreire.esy.es/Treinamentoslista.html#dsg7

Ou seja, pode inserir logo no link direto:

```
...
<a href="Treinamentoslista.html#dsg7" target="_self">
...
```

O mesmo pode fazer para os outros